# disabling a specific powershell 7.2.1 keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows, powershell, keyboard-shortcuts

[basically this,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbbvL.jpg)
when im switching between japanese IME and english with alt+~(actually it's alt+`) powershell 7.2.1 adds an @ at the same time and it's annoying having to delete it each time, i didn't have the same problem when i was using the default powershell that comes preinstalled on windows 10, nor with cmd, is there a way to disable this shortcut specifically on powershell 7.2.1? any help would be appreciated

Comment: The usual shortcut for changing languages is Alt-Shift. How come that yours is different?

Comment: @harrymc my bad i should've provided more details, the japanese keyboard itself has japanese as well as english and one can change between them by alt+` so there's no need to have both japanese and english keyboards installed, i also use the persian keyboard and im just not used to switching between 3 languages with alt+shift.

Comment: That's a funny keyboard, if it both uses this key combination to change layouts and also transmits it on to Windows. Are you sure it's working correctly? Is there perhaps a firmware update for it?

Comment: Have you reported this bug to the [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) team?

Comment: @harrymc yes it's up to date and i don't have any problem with it except in powershell, version 7.2.1 that is, since it still works fine on the preinstalled version and doesn't add an at sign whenever i use that key combination.

Comment: Does [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/revert-to-a-previous-version-of-an-ime-input-method-editor-adcc9caa-17cb-44d8-b46e-f5b473b4dd77) help?

Comment: @harrymc already tried that but no powershell still adds a random @ each time, i also saw that other people are having the same problem, i wish there was an easy way around it but it seems like there isn't

Comment: @Ramhound i went ahead to do so but i realized other people are having the same issue and it seems like there hasn't been a fix yet

Comment: @aminkh04 - There might not be a solution or a resolution to the problem.

Comment: Does this also happen in Windows Terminal.?

Comment: @harrymc yes im pretty sure it has to do with powershell itself since cmd and windows powershell or the preinstalled version of powershell work fine in or outside of windows terminal, i researched some more and realized a lot of people have the same issue and it's mind bugging that there hasn't been a fix for such a simple yet annoying issue yet

Answer (score 1):

it looks like this is an older open issue with a handful of related projects:

- Powershell core: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13368
- PSReadLine: https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/2206
- .NET runtime: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/63034

but mostly due to how the microsoft IME uses new(?) language input keys. It seems to occur when using <kbd>ALT</kbd> key-combinations to switch input methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in PowerShell that was signaled in the bug-report
[Alt+~ stroke that turns IME on and off makes to insert the unexpected '@' character #13368](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13368).
This PowerShell issue is marked as a
[PSReadLine](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine)
bug.

This issue is indeed signaled for PSReadLine in the bug-report
[Some keys on Japanese layout keyboards are incorrectly interpreted as @ #2206](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/2206).

The last entry in the bug-report, from Jan 9, 2022, says:

> When I tried the new Microsoft-IME, pressing the "Muhenkan" key no longer typed "@".
> However, as mentioned earlier, the new Microsoft-IME has many bugs.

So you can perhaps fix the problem by installing the latest version of
PSReadLine, but may encounter new bugs.

You should track new releases of PowerShell and install them as
they come out. The bug might be well fixed in the future.

In the meantime, I suggest raising any issues you find in the forums
of PowerShell and PSReadLine.